# Netdata api for traffic of specific docker image

Tags: netdata

I have a server running several docker containers. I wanted to know about network usage of individual and some specific docker containers.
I wad able to get entire traffic using below api

```
http://<server-ip>:19999/api/v1/data?chart=net.docker0&after=-60&before=0&points=1&group=median&gtime=0&format=json&options=seconds&options=jsonwrap
```

I goes through documentations and didn't find anything helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the issue with such questions comes from Netdata not being granted the access required to identify the docker container.

I'd take a look at https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/packaging/docker/#docker-container-names-resolution and go through https://github.com/netdata/netdata/issues/6882 as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the specific container name then you should i think just be able to pull the data direct from the container specific chart.

For example i have a container called `airbyte-webapp` and so i can get its network usage via its own specific chart at `/api/v1/data?chart=cgroup_airbyte-webapp.net_eth0`

[image]